# Help with GDB on a C++ program

Tags: c++, gdb

I am new to Ubuntu and am using the 12.04 version on my laptop. I am trying to execute a C++ program which has Petsc libraries installed in it. I get an error when trying to run the program and so have installed GDB in Ubuntu.

The name of the program is ex1.c and is located in a folder called 'petsc-3.1-p8' on my computer. How do I run gdb in the terminal to see what is the error while I run this program?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the file extensions (`.c`), I assume that `ex1.c` is a C source file. You must first compile the source code before you can debug the application with GDB. Assuming you have GCC installed (available from the [gcc package [image: Install gcc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc)), you can do this with:

```
gcc ex1.c -g -o ex1
```

Once compiled, you can debug the application by running:

```
gdb ex1
```

This will load the executable and dump you at the GDB prompt. You can then start the application by running the following command at the prompt:

```
run
```

If the program crashes, you can inspect the calling stack by running:

```
backtrace
```

Comment: Should the `gcc` line also include `-g`?

Comment: @chaskes: Ah, good point. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for the reply.
I am able to compile the code using the command 'make ex1'.I am getting an error while executing the code using 'mpiexec -n 1 -m 200 -n 80 -q 32 -ntimes 10'. So, do I have to run the GDB command after executing the code or after compiling the code?

Please bear with me, I am a newbie and have a lots of doubts. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user170775: The code must be compiled before running GDB. GDB itself will execute the code when you enter the "run" command.